# Vector fields for volumetric-deviatoric decomposition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

The strain tensor $\epsilon(u) = \frac12 (\nabla u + (\nabla u)^T)$ in linear elasticity can be decomposed additively into volumetric and deviatoric strains
\begin{gather*}
\epsilon_D(u) &= \epsilon(u) - \tfrac13 \nabla \cdot  u \;\mathbb 1
=
\begin{cases}
\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_1u_1-\partial_2u_2 &  \partial_2u_1+\partial_1u_2 \\
 \partial_2u_1+\partial_1u_2 & \partial_2 u_2 - \partial_1 u_1
\end{pmatrix} & \text{in two dimensions},
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2\partial_1u_1 - \partial_2 u_2 - \partial_3 u_3}3
& \frac{\partial_1u_2+\partial_2u_1}2
& \frac{\partial_1u_3+\partial_3u_1}2
\\
\frac{\partial_1u_2+\partial_2u_1}2
&\frac{2\partial_2u_2 - \partial_1 u_1 - \partial_3 u_3}3
& \frac{\partial_2u_3+\partial_3u_2}2
\\
\frac{\partial_1u_3+\partial_3u_1}2
& \frac{\partial_2u_3+\partial_3u_2}2
&\frac{2\partial_3u_3 - \partial_1 u_1 - \partial_2 u_2}3
\end{pmatrix}& \text{in three dimensions},
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
with $\epsilon_D(u):\mathbb 1 = 0$. Thus, Lamé-Navier equations in weak form decouple nicely into
$$
2 \mu (\epsilon_D(u),\epsilon_D(v)) + (2\mu+\lambda) (\nabla \cdot u, \nabla \cdot v) = (f,v)
$$

First question: is there a decomposition similar to Helmholtz decomposition of an arbitrary vector function $u\in C^1$ into $u=u_D+u_V$, such that
$$
\epsilon_D(u_V) = 0 \quad \wedge \quad \nabla\cdot u_D = 0?
$$
Second question: is there such a decomposition of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ into closed subspaces for suitable domains $\Omega$?

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, $\epsilon_D(u_V)=0$ would locally imply that $i$-th component of $u_V$ is a function of $i$-th coordinate only.  Thus $\nabla u_V=f(x)+g(y)+h(z)$ and definitely is not enough to cancel an arbitrary $\nabla u$.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk: I just added the deviatoric strain in Cartesian coordinates. Your suggestion eliminates the off-diagonal terms, but then the diagonals imply $f(x)=g(y)=h(z)$ in every point, and thus $u_V$ linear